# Possible Methods to retrieve image from server

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, base64, android-imageview

I am developing an application where it should get data from my server with respect to the ID Number , and also I need to take an image from database , according to the id number. So I went to an option of loading url image. There I could not able to get large size images. So I went to converting the image to base64 format and sending it through webservice. Even in that I was able to retrieve small size strings , but when I go for big size of images, the base64 string is bigger. So looking for possible answers, any way thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending photos in binary form over a HTTP connection is a solved problem.  I suggest you go with an off-the-shelf web server and call it a day.  To send reduced-size images, install a script that (in response to a URL that indicates desire for a thumbnail) will check for thumbnails; create them if they don't exist; and then serve as images in the standard manner.  Don't worry about base64 unless you're dealing with really ancient services that don't understand pure binaries.  If you do go the route of base64, don't worry about file-size expansion.  Unless you're sending huge numbers of images, it's not that significant.

Comment: i'm using dotnet webservice to run in server side ,And java on android  . Here i tried to fetch a image from data base and convert it to base 64 format and send as string through the webservice ,but i could not get the whole string , its some where missing and returns as half empty string

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and had to use ftp server. I put my image files into a ftp server and download each one I need.

Comment: already tried with loading image as url  but it works only for small images not for large size images